# How to export TensorFlow training data to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I'm running a SVM sentiment analysis project and I wanted to vectorize it using tf-idf. the code snip for the tf-idf section is below:

```
X = table_tfidf

y = df['label']

random_state = 42

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_text = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=random_state)

#dividing training data to train data and validation data

X_train_train, X_train_val, y_train_train, y_train_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size = 0.2)
```

how do I export the X_train and the y_train only data into a .csv file? I wanted to check if the data were properly split. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
X_train.to_csv('X_train.csv')
```